# Create Column based on multiple time conditions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I have a table (that is recreated as part of a query) with the following columns:

ID, Period (which is the number of Months, as an Integer), Payment date, Purchased Date.

I want to create a 5th column in the process: New

The calculation for which would be:

If the Payment date is within X Months of the Purchase date (where X is the number of Months) then 1.

I'm sure that this will be `case` expression - but I'm not sure how to do the calculation part in the `case` expression.

Comment: Probably didn't articulate it well - the Table is created by a Stored Procedure - I've rolled the below bit of code into the SP for when the table is created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just want a `case` expression?  Something like this:

```
select t.*,
       (case when purchasedate >= paymentdate and
                  purchasedate < dateadd(month, X, paymentdate)
             then 1 else 0
        end)
from t;
```

Comment: Perfect - didn't realise you could use dateadd and define a column to get the integer value